# cakephp how to remove authcomponent errors

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. the problem which i have is whenever there is an error comes on my webapp ..these error always shows on the top of the page and then the actual error come..

> AuthComponent::identify() must be an instance of CakeRequest, null
>   given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\allsecure\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php
>   on line 547 and defined
>   [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php
>
> Argument 2 passed to AuthComponent::identify() must be an instance of
>   CakeResponse, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\allsecure\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php
>   on line 547 and defined
>   [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php, line 690]
>
> Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to FormAuthenticate::authenticate()
>   must be an instance of CakeRequest, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\allsecure\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php
>   on line 695 and defined
>   [CORE\Cake\Controller\Component\Auth\FormAuthenticate.php, line 70]

and then the actual error comes e.g

> Missing Controller action ..

how can i remove these above auth errors

Comment: The error message already tells you what is wrong, just read it. Debug the cause, follow the stack trace. I don't know what you're doing to mess the initialization of the core classes up.

Comment: Post the code that's causing the error.

Comment: @well this error comes whenever there is something wrong in my code .. for example whenever an action is missing or i haven't created a view page ... it shows these error first and then the actual errors. these errors remains constant .. and when i resolve the actual error .. then everythng works works

Comment: @hellosheikh Did you find an answer to your issue?

Comment: @TekiusFanatikus nope